# Error message when running a model from spacy package

Tags: python, spacy

I installed spacy package using 'pip install spacy' and the I installed a model using $ python -m spacy download pt_core_news_sm. The installation was successful. The message I got after the installation was:

Requirement already satisfied: pt_core_news_sm==2.1.0 from https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/pt_core_news_sm-2.1.0/pt_core_news_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz#egg=pt_core_news_sm==2.1.0 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.1.0)
✔ Download and installation successful
You can now load the model via spacy.load('pt_core_news_sm')

However, when I run spacy.load("pt_core_news_sm") using python idle, I get a error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       spacy.load("pt_core_news_sm")   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/**init**.py",
>   line 27, in load
>       return util.load_model(name, **overrides)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py",
>   line 136, in load_model
>       raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name)) OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'pt_core_news_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a
>   Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

Why am I getting this message if the installation was successful?

Can anyone help me to figure out what is going on? I want to run POS tagger to my texts in Portuguese

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the same python installation in your command line and inside the python idle.

You can compare the ouptut of the `sys.path` command, which tells you the PYTHONPATH used.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run spaCy by setting an environment.
In you'r case maybe your model is not installed correctly, reninstall the model `pt_core_news_sm`